# Changing java heap size via maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm using the following as a means to determine if changing the java heap size via adding:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

to my bash_profile actually does what I want it to do (I'm on mac OS 10.9.3 if that matters).

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long totalMem = rt.totalMemory();
    long maxMem = rt.maxMemory();
    long freeMem = rt.freeMemory();
    double megs = 1048576.0;

    System.out.println ("Total Memory: " + totalMem + 
                        " (" + (totalMem/megs) + " MiB)");
    System.out.println ("Max Memory:   " + maxMem + 
                        " (" + (maxMem/megs) + " MiB)");
    System.out.println ("Free Memory:  " + freeMem + 
                        " (" + (freeMem/megs) + " MiB)");
```

Even after recompiling/assembling via maven, none of the above change.  Is there something else that I need to do for this to take effect? NB: I sourced my bash_profile after adding the export, and when I execute:

```
echo $MAVEN_OPTS
```

it is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

[is passed to maven's jvm](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/61c374042560b2dc21c294886615931a888df597/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn#L194) and it doesn't apply on the application you compile/launch using maven

You still need to pass this argument explicitly to JVM of your application

Comment: it is if your app is too big and it takes more heap to compile, validate, package, etc.. you need to increase heap of maven's jvm itself